# Error when dividing results from SQL

Tags: sql, razor, webmatrix

I have a problem with a SQL query that I don'tr understand:
I am using WebMatrix with razor syntax.
I want to query my stock table and find how many of my top movers are in stock, as a percentage.

In the code bolock, i have:

```
var topmovers = db.QueryValue("select COUNT(STOCKCODE) from dbo.STOCK_ITEMS where STOCK_CLASSIFICATION = 170") ?? 0;   

var instock = db.QueryValue("select COUNT(STOCKCODE) from dbo.STOCK_ITEMS where STOCK_CLASSIFICATION = 170 and TOTALSTOCK > 0") ?? 0;   

var ofpc = instock/topmovers;`
```

then in the body, i have

```
@ofpc.ToString("P2")
```

It returns either 0 or 100, depending on which way around I have the variables `instock` and `topmovers`. I want a percentage, not 100% or 0%!

If i go `@instock.ToString();` i get 862

If I go `@topmovers.ToString();` i get 965

According to my maths, 862/965 is 0.8932 (89.32%)

However, I am getting 0.00% as the result of `ofpc` when I output it with `@ofpc.ToString("P2")`

I'm obviously wrong somewhere...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same problem happens in SQL Server, which does integer division, so:

```
select 1/2
```

Always returns 0.

So, you need to cast one of the values to a floating point number.  Can you use this expression:

```
var ofpc = cast(instock as float)/topmovers;
```

Or something similar?  Perhaps:

```
var ofpc = (instock*1.0)/topmovers
```

You can also make the database return a floating point value:

```
var topmovers = db.QueryValue("select cast(COUNT(STOCKCODE) as float) from dbo.STOCK_ITEMS where STOCK_CLASSIFICATION = 170") ?? 0;`
```

What I've done is convert the first count to a float inside SQL.  You can undoubtedly do this at the application level, but I'm more familiar with SQL.  This should make the `topmovers` variable a float, and the division will be a floating point division.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand this. I have done as you suggest, but now the page crashes with "compilation error"

Comment: @jamesmohler, and Gordon - Well done guys, and thanks. fixed and working.